# I can't send a DM to a user using user ID

Tags: discord.js

I tried code from the documentation, this site and much more, but all of them give me the same error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
This is my code: `const user = client.users.cache.get('id-here'); user.send('test');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of recent changes in Discord's API that took effect last October, Discord.js will only cache users that needed caching, such as users that sent a message or similar. Because of this, a user needs to be fetched first. To do so, you have to use [`UserManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch).

Since `client.users` is a `UserManager`, you can call the following in order to send a message to the user:

```js
client.users.fetch('id-here').then(user => {
    user.send('test');
})
```

Since `.fetch()` is a Promise, you have to use `.then` (or use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)) in order to grab the result of the Promise, which is the [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) that the ID corresponds to, in this case.